# Proper way of clearing forms without redux-form

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux

This is my form

```
<form className="input-group" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <input className="form-control"
   type="text"
   placeholder="Insert name"
   autofocus="true" />
   <span className="input-group-btn">
     <button type="submit" className={classNames}>Add</button>
   </span>
</form>
```

This is my event handler:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 let name = e.target[0].value;
 if (name.length > 0) {
  this.props.dispatch(createClassroom(name));
 }
}
```

My question is:

what's the proper "redux way" to clearing the form after submitting it?
Do I need to dispatch a different action or should I use the existing `createClassroom` action?

Note: I'd rather not use redux-form package.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using controlled input, how could you clear it via dispatching action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to make sure that the `<input>` is a [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) by passing its respective value from the state:

```
const { classroom } = this.props;

// in return:
<input type="text" value={ classroom.name } />
```

Then, the form can be cleared by ideally submitting a `RESET` action that your `classroom` reducer acts upon:

```
const initialState = {};

function classroomReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case 'RESET_CLASSROOM':
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: In hindsight, my question wasn't very well phrased. However, your answer helped, thanks.